# SaltStack: NPM install package with --unsafe-perm

Tags: node.js, npm, salt-stack

Can I set `unsafe-perm` to `true` when installing npm packages?

```
npm-pkgs:
  npm.installed:
    - names:
      - composer-cli
      - generator-hyperledger-composer
```

The reason for that is that I ran into a permission issue when trying to install some of the packages:

> gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev
>   dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js/.node-gyp/8.9.3"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using env vars [NpmDoc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables), [SaltNpmDoc](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.npm.html#salt.states.npm.installed)

```
npm-pkgs:
  npm.installed:
    - names:
      - composer-cli
      - generator-hyperledger-composer
    - env:
      - npm_config_unsafe_perm: "true"
```

Comment: I cannot confirm if this is working at the moment because I don't have that setup running anymore. Maybe something was added in the newer `salt` releases?